# In a JavaScript Discord Bot, how come message.react() is "not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.io

I'm running a discord bot on my server. I want to make the bot `message.react()` to the message I just got. When I run this it works fine until I send a message.

I get this error:

```
/Users/*****/Projects/Discord/DiscordBot/bot.js:22
    .react("")
     ^

TypeError: message.react is not a function
    at DiscordClient.bot.on (/Users/revel/Projects/Discord/DiscordBot/bot.js:22:6)
    at DiscordClient.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at DiscordClient.handleWSMessage (/Users/revel/Projects/Discord/DiscordBot/node_modules/discord.io/lib/index.js:1854:11)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Receiver.ontext (/Users/revel/Projects/Discord/DiscordBot/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:841:10)
    at /Users/revel/Projects/Discord/DiscordBot/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:536:18
    at Receiver.applyExtensions (/Users/revel/Projects/Discord/DiscordBot/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:371:5)
    at /Users/revel/Projects/Discord/DiscordBot/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:508:14
    at Receiver.flush (/Users/revel/Projects/Discord/DiscordBot/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:347:3)
    at Receiver.finish (/Users/revel/Projects/Discord/DiscordBot/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:541:12)
```

Here's my code:

```
var Discord = require("discord.io");
var logger = require("winston");
var auth = require("./auth.json");
// Configure logger settings
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console(), {
  colorize: true,
});
logger.level = "debug";
// Initialize Discord Bot
var bot = new Discord.Client({
  token: auth.token,
  autorun: true,
});
bot.on("ready", function (evt) {
  logger.info("Connected");
  logger.info("Logged in as: ");
  logger.info(bot.username + " - (" + bot.id + ")");
});
bot.on("message", (message) => {
  message.react("");
});
```

I'm running `discord.js` version `12.2.0` Can you help?

Comment: This is not Discord.js, It's Discord.io

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using discord.io, not discord.js.

If you want to add a reaction, you need to replace your message event listener with this:

```js
bot.on("message", (user, userID, channelID, message, event) => {
  bot.addReaction({
    channelID,
    messageID: event.d.id,
    reaction: ""
  });
});
```

**References:**

- [`client.on('message', function(user, userID, channelID, message, event) { });`](https://izy521.gitbooks.io/discord-io/content/Events/Client.html)
- [`client.addReaction({ })`](https://izy521.github.io/discord.io-docs/Discord.Client.html#addReaction)
- [`event.d.id`](https://github.com/izy521/discord.io/issues/74#issuecomment-225595273)

Answer (score 1):

Just gave a quick look at [discord.io's docs](https://izy521.gitbooks.io/discord-io/content/Events/Client.html#message),
You should replace the `message` event's parameters with the correct ones, as described in the link :

```js
client.on('message', function(user, userID, channelID, message, event) { });
```